# Is there a project setting that controls getting to Game Center's Sandbox?

Tags: iphone, game-center

This is different from the others; it's cool.

I know that your Bundle Identifier needs to match your iTunes Connect's version.  I know you need to make a new AppleID through your dev app and not through Game Center.  Most people get this fixed when they force quit their app and game center and launch theirs first.

I am not one of those people.

If I take the GKTapper tutorial and use my game's Bundle Identifier as the only change, things are good.  On launch, it asks me if I want to use an existing or make a new account.  But more importantly, it says *** Sandbox ***.  (Before I log in, mind you; this is not an account problem at all.)  Once inside I can see my achievements.

If I load my game, I has a sad.  On launch I get the same dialog, but it does not say Sandbox.  My game is two weeks away from being done after many long months.  Moving everything in to a new project is possible, but a pain.  So the question is:

What magic setting does GKTapper or a new project have that my game that I started in June does not that lets you get to Game Center's Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

YOU HAVE GOT TO BE KIDDING ME.

The "***Sandbox***" tag doesn't show up in landscape.  It worked the whole time.  I would delete this question but people need to be able to search for this.  I just enabled portrait and flipped back and forth and watched Sandbox appear and disappear through my tears.